# Read updated objects in git db versioning

Tags: git

I use git only for my code, but if i'm not mistaken, git can also be used for database version control, creating the DDL scripts for database objects.

My question is:

> after a commit or a push, is there a git command (or any other command) I can use to get a list of changed objects?

I would like to get the name of those objects and pass it to an external API.

E.G. I create a new table named *"shrubberies"* and one named *"knights"*

Git will create a script like *"dbo.Dgtal.Shrubberies.sql"* and one like *"dbo.Dgtal.Knights"*.

Can i have a list of those objects names with a git command (or any other command/tool)?

Comment: Git doesn't know anything about objects or database or DDL scripts. Or put differently: you are mistaken or are misremembering something. There *are* tools that create DDL scripts from some code, but they are unrelated to git. The changed "objects" that git can tell you about are just files: it can give you a list of changed files, but if you need anything other than that, you'll have to use other tools.

Comment: If you just want the list of files that were modified between commit `<source>` and commit `<target>`, that's simply : `git diff --name-only <source> <target>`, or with a letter indicating 'Added/Modified/Delete' : `git diff --name-status <source> <target>`.

Comment: `git help diff` or https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff for a detailed description of what you will get

Comment: I'll do some more research as soon as i can, but i'm afraid @JoachimSauer is right.